# How can I call a method within an AngularJS directive from within a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This might be a simple question but I'm updating some old AngularJS code and my knowledge is a bit rusty.

If I have an AngularJS directive, like below:

As you can see I have a reload method in there. Is there anyway I can call that method from within   the controller code?

I know you can add method binding within the scope object but this is for the directive to call.

```
scope: {
    reload: '&'
}
```

How can I do it so the controller calls the directive method?

Directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var myDirective= function () {

        var vm = $scope;

        var controller = function ($scope, $injector) {

            vm.reload = function () {
                console.log('reloading);
            };               

        var link = function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {


        };

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {

            },
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            link: link,
            controller: controller
        };
    }

    angular.module('App').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("App").controller("myCtlr", MyController);

    function MyController($scope) {

        this.form = {};

        this.init = function () {
            console.log('Init...');
        }

        this.reload = function () {
            console.log("searching...");

            //CALL THE DIRECTIVE Reload method here
        }
    }
})();
```

page HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtlr as model" data-ng-init="model.init()">
    <button ng-click="model.reload()">Reload<button>
    <my-directive>
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your controller you can use:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event_name')
```

on your directive template, use the following attribute to capture the event emition:

```
directive-attribute-name="event_name"
```

on your directive:

```
scope.$on(attrs.directiveAttributeName, function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      //... do stuff here ...
   });
});
```